# Get the version from distutils setup.py

Tags: python, distutils

How can I import or read the VERSION from the setup.py file so that I can log the version at runtime.
This way I can make sure that the results obtained are from this particular version of my package.

The following is the contents of my setup.py file (simplified to have the necessary part)

```
import distutils.core
VERSION = '0.1.0'
LICENSE = 'GPLv2'
distutils.core.setup(**KWARGS)
```

When I try to do :
    import setup
I get the following error:

```
distutils.core.setup(**KWARGS)
usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.pyc in setup(**attrs)
        ok = dist.parse_command_line()
    except DistutilsArgError, msg:
        raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg

    if DEBUG:

SystemExit: 

error: no commands supplied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yor example, setup is excecuted automatically, you have to replace:

```
distutils.core.setup(**KWARGS)
```

with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    distutils.core.setup(**KWARGS)
```

Like this, setup is only executed if you actually run the setup.py

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to get the version from your setup script:

```
python setup.py --version
```

But I’m not sure I understand what you mean with “log the version at runtime”; the setup script is normally not installed with your modules, so people use other ways to put a version number in their code, like a `__version__` attribute in their module or `__init__.py` file.